# Drawing Border on a QListWidget item makes the text disappear on clicking

Tags: qt, qt5

I tried setting a border to `QListWidget` items using the following line:

```
mListwidget->setStyleSheet("QListWidget:item{height: 40px;border-left: 2px solid red;}");
```

with `mListwidget` being the `QListWidget`.

When I run the code, I get the red border needed, but when I click the QListWidgetItem, the text on it disappears.

I'm attaching the pics for the reference.
This is what it looks like [before clicking the QListWidget Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWDsP.png) and this is what happens [after clicking an item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Y9s.png).

Answer (score 3):

The text disappeared because you forgot to define the selected style: QListWidget::item:selected

See the code below:

```
mListwidget->setStyleSheet("QListWidget:item{height: 40px;border-left: 2px solid red;}QListWidget::item:selected {background-color: white; color: black}");
```

Example and other information [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qlistview).

Comment: I had tried doing something like that, but the problem is that it doesn't show the default selection color when we do that.
I have this problem on Mac as well, when i set the selection color, it works just fine, but i want it to change according to system settings.

Comment: You could then implement an slot on_listWidget_itemClicked that when called, it will change the QListWidgetItem stylesheet to system default or to any other stylesheet you want.

Comment: I Tried setting it to system default through a slot but then i lose the changes that i make.
The main problem is that when i add an icon on the right side of the list widget item, the text shifts to the left when it is selected and active.
To tackle that, i used this: QListWidget:item[/* property*]{ border: 2px solid red;}(tried for active condition as well)
When i do this, it solves the text shifting issue, but then i don't get the default selection color & on calling the default stylesheet, i get the selection color but unfortunately, the text shifting issue recurs